# json Decode error expecting value

Tags: python, json

I really need help understanding what this error means.
Everything runs perfectly fine for a couple of hours but then this pops up an it stops. I got this project online and I've already spent days fixing other errors and trying to change things to fit my needs but, i'm extremely new to this.

```
May 17 00:45:29 raspberrypi rc.local[393]:     response=requests.get("https://beta.todoist.com/API/v8/tasks", params={"token":TODOIST_TOKEN}).json()

May 17 00:45:29 raspberrypi rc.local[393]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 850, in json

May 17 00:45:29 raspberrypi rc.local[393]:     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

May 17 00:45:29 raspberrypi rc.local[393]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 516, in loads

May 17 00:45:29 raspberrypi rc.local[393]:     return _default_decoder.decode(s)

May 17 00:45:29 raspberrypi rc.local[393]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 374, in decode

May 17 00:45:29 raspberrypi rc.local[393]:     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)

May 17 00:45:29 raspberrypi rc.local[393]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 404, in raw_decode

May 17 00:45:29 raspberrypi rc.local[393]:     return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

May 17 00:45:29 raspberrypi rc.local[393]: simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I think this is the part of the python file that's giving me trouble.

```
def is_todo_changed():
response=requests.get("https://beta.todoist.com/API/v8/tasks", params={"token":TODOIST_TOKEN}).json()
global todolist_items
get_todolist_items= len (response)

if(get_todolist_items!=todolist_items):
    print('items changed')
    return True

response=requests.get("https://beta.todoist.com/API/v8/tasks", params={"token":TODOIST_TOKEN}).json()
data=response
global todolist_items
todolist_items=len(data)
```

Comment: It means the server did not return JSON.

Comment: That code isn't doing any error checking. The server returned an empty string which isn't valid json so you got the exception. Consider breaking your get into two steps. First, do the request (without a .json()`) and check for errors, then do the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is probably rate-limiting you. Rather than calling `.json()` directly on the result of calling `.get()`, you should save the response to a variable and check the status:

```
response = requests.get(...)
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
```